# What can one do to secure holes described by Arnaboldi?

Tags: php, vulnerability, known-vulnerabilities

I have just read: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-17/materials/eu-17-Arnaboldi-Exposing-Hidden-Exploitable-Behaviors-In-Programming-Languages-Using-Differential-Fuzzing-wp.pdf

Which describes some security flaws in (amongst others) PHP. What can I do to secure these holes? And how seriously should they be taken?

Appreciate a second eye on this.

Comment: The paper describes an approach to discovering vulnerabilities, it doesn't really relate to a specific class of vulnerabilities and therefore doesn't suggest there could be a common way to fix the bugs found with this approach. And if there was, it would IMO be proably more of a research topic than a quick SE answer.